# Displaying Jtree on selecting item from JComboBox?

Tags: java, swing, jtree

I need to construct tree on action listener of JComboBox

```
public class ExpressionTree extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    private JComboBox group;    
    private JLabel groupLabel;
    Container content;
    JTree tree;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new ExpressionTree();
    }


    public ExpressionTree() {

        super("Creating a Simple JTree");
        WindowUtilities.setNativeLookAndFeel();
        addWindowListener(new ExitListener());
        content = getContentPane();

        group = new JComboBox();
        groupLabel = new JLabel("GROUP");

        ExpressionBuilder expressionBuilder = new ExpressionBuilder(); 
        Set<Integer> set = expressionBuilder.getGroup().keySet();
        Iterator<Integer> iterator = set.iterator();
        group.addItem("select");
        while(iterator.hasNext()){
            group.addItem(expressionBuilder.getGroup().get(iterator.next()));       
        }


        content.add(groupLabel);
        content.add(group);
        group.addActionListener(this);
        content.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        tree = new JTree();
        content.add(new JScrollPane(tree), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        setSize(300, 475);
        setVisible(true);

    }
    public String groupString = null;
    public int groupId;

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){

        groupString = group.getSelectedItem().toString();
        ExpressionBuilder builder=new ExpressionBuilder();
        builder.getGroupId(groupString);
        _____//what to write here to see the tree
    }
}
```

---

```
public class NodeTree  extends DefaultMutableTreeNode{

    private JTree tree;
    public NodeTree(){
            ExpressionTree expressionTree= new ExpressionTree();
            String groupstring = expressionTree.groupString;
            int groupId = expressionTree.groupId;
            DefaultMutableTreeNode top = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(groupstring);
            tree = new JTree(top);
            tree.setEditable(true);
            JScrollPane treeView = new JScrollPane(tree);
            createNode(top,groupId);

    }

    public void createNode(DefaultMutableTreeNode top,int group){
        DefaultMutableTreeNode expression[] = null;
        ExpressionBuilder builder=new ExpressionBuilder();
        Object object = (Object)builder.getExpression(group,0);
        top.add(expression[1]);
        expression[1] = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(object);     
        expression[1].add(new     DefaultMutableTreeNode((Object)builder.getExpression(group,1)));

    }
}
```

i am using above file to create a tree.

Comment: Create a tree where? Could you explain what your are trying to accomplish and what your code currently does?

Comment: It is showing me combo box with default tree. But i want tree to be rendered when user select something from combo box. When user select something from combo box data corresponding to the selected item from database is needed to added to the tree.

Answer (score 1):

```
tree.setModel(new DefaultTreeModel(theTreeRootNode));
```

Comment: expression[1] = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(object);  this is trwing me error of NullPointer exception. My object is of String type. Can we convert String Object to DefaultMutableTreeNode? Thanks

Comment: @Chirag, no you need to put your String in a Node.